# What is the right way to escape a bash variable to be correctly expanded in HTML?

Tags: html, bash, variables, escaping

I have this piece of code for adding a link to an index.html in a directory based on a timestamp. `$(tstampm)` is a function that generates a timestamp.

```
export tstampm=$(tstampm)
echo 'output from sysuser database - <a href="sysuser/model01-$tstampm"</a> <br />'  >> /home/sysuser/docs/dbmodels/index.html
```

The quotes in the href prevent expansion of the bash variable. What is the correct syntax for getting it expanded?

Note that the double quotes for the `href` are enclosed in single quotes for the `echo` command itself.

Comment: Note: the Linux shell is totally unaware of HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are expanded inside double quotes, they're not expanded inside single quotes.

```
echo "output from sysuser database - <a href='sysuser/model01-$tstampm'></a> <br />"  >> /home/sysuser/docs/dbmodels/index.html
```

You were also missing the closing `>` of the `<a>` tag. And you probably want something between `<a>` and `</a>`, so there will be something to click on.

Answer (score 1):

As @Bramar says, and you can directly call your `tmstamp` as I call the date in the next example:

```
echo "output from sysuser database - <a href=\"sysuser/model01-$(date +%s)\">some text</a> <br />"
```

produces

```
output from sysuser database - <a href="sysuser/model01-1410439138">some text</a> <br />
```

Comment: the `tstampm` variable must be computed once and exported, as it has to be the same in subsequent related commands